# Angular 2 button right click for new tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am using this for navigating to another page of my app.

```
<a (click)="navigate()">Edit</a>

navigate(){
  this.router.navigate(['/edit-page'])
}
```

Instead of just clicking it for navigating to the edit page, I also want to right click it and open it in a new tab, but when I right click it there is no new tab option.

Comment: every a tag will have that option.are you sure you have that option for any other link?

Comment: you should use `[routerLink]="'/edit-page'"` with `target="_bank"` if you want it to open in new tab and make sure you have imported the `RouterModule` in your `@ngModule`

Comment: @RemyaJ I am not sure that I understood your question. if you could rephrase it I might understand what you mean.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi I don't want to open it in a new tab every time and I think this works only for opening in new tab.

Comment: @dimitrismaf if you don't won't to open it on new tab then only use `[routerLink]="'/edit-page'"`

Comment: @TouqeerShafi it seems to work but it is half of the solution I need. With the  navigate method I can functionality before the redirection. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out... you can specify **both** [href] and [routerLink] like this:

```
<a href="/edit-page" [routerLink]="['edit-page']">Edit</a>
```

When right clicking the link, the browser menu will show options to open in new tab, open in new window.

When left clicking the link, the router link will navigate to the specified page without reloading the overall app.

Comment: I am afraid I was aiming to achieve this without using the routerLink/href option, since I would like to handle the navigation from the controller. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: I had the same goal, eventually settled on a dynamic string for the url and array for the router link returned by a function in the controller... not quite what I hoped, but still test friendly.